# Quaternion transformations in Python

Tags: ros, python, quaternion, tf-conversions, transformations

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to place some Markers in RViz, using a node written in Python. To this end, I need to create a `geometry_msgs.mgs.Pose` with an `orientation` Quaternion.

But I can't for the life of me find the utility and conversion functions that I need for Quaternions. There are *some* in `tf.transformations`, but those produce `numpy` Quaternions, which I would have to manually split up and throw into the `geometry_msgs.msg.Quaternion` constructor.

Considering that Quaternions are of little use without a set of functions to work with them, my question is: **Where are the proper conversion functions for Quaternions?** That is, functions to  create and modify `geometry_msgs.msg.Quaternion` or to convert between a `numpy` Quaternion (4-tuple) and `geometry_msgs.msg.Quaternion` (object with x,y,z,w attributes).

My environment is Ubuntu 12.04 Precise, with ROS fuerte (using fuerte is currently mandatory for this project; I'm already looking into upgrading, but that's not at all easy).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69754/quaternion-transformations-in-python/) by [nevik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5620/nevik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also remember having problems with this a few months back, the documentation is not overly clear; but in the end it is very simple.

To convert from euler to quaternion:

```
quaternion = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw)
#type(pose) = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose
pose.orientation.x = quaternion[0]
pose.orientation.y = quaternion[1]
pose.orientation.z = quaternion[2]
pose.orientation.w = quaternion[3]
```

And to convert from quaternion to euler:

```
#type(pose) = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose
quaternion = (
    pose.orientation.x,
    pose.orientation.y,
    pose.orientation.z,
    pose.orientation.w)
euler = tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion(quaternion)
roll = euler[0]
pitch = euler[1]
yaw = euler[2]
```

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 47

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vtalpaert](https://answers.ros.org/users/27555/vtalpaert/) on 2016-08-16**:
As an update in 2016, it could be written as:

```
pose.orientation = geometry_msgs.msg.Quaternion(*tf_conversions.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw))
```

**Comment by [Combinacijus](https://answers.ros.org/users/44007/combinacijus/) on 2021-03-22**:
Also remember to import

```
import tf
import geometry_msgs
```

And for someone who doesn't know star "*" here *tf_conversions in python is an *unpacking operator* which as name suggests unpacks list to separate argument for the function

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To convert from a numpy array to a Quaternion message type, it's just:

```
q = numpy.array([.5, .5, .5, .5])
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion
pub.publish(Quaternion(*q))
```

Converting from the message type to a numpy array is harder and I could never find a provided function, so I usually do:

```
xyzw_array = lambda o: numpy.array([o.x, o.y, o.z, o.w])
print xyz_array(msg.pose.orientation)
```

---

Originally posted by [forrestv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3689/forrestv/) with karma: 154 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way you make this work is:

> explicit_quat = [quaternion.x, quaternion.y, quaternion.z, quaternion.w]

> your_euler = tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion(explicit_quat)

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [The Construct](https://answers.ros.org/users/27056/the-construct/) with karma: 41 on 2017-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following example can help you understand how to use the conversion from quaternions provided by an Odometry message to Euler angles Roll, Pitch and Yaw.

In the following example, you can see that the program subscribes to the odometry topic to get the orientation of a Turtlebot3 robot. Then it uses the tf.transformation functions to obtain the yaw value (the actual 'z' value or orientation of the odometry).

Then the program uses the roll, pitch and yaw to convert them back into a quaternion.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion, quaternion_from_euler

roll = pitch = yaw = 0.0

def get_rotation (msg):
    global roll, pitch, yaw
    orientation_q = msg.pose.pose.orientation
    orientation_list = [orientation_q.x, orientation_q.y, orientation_q.z, orientation_q.w]
    (roll, pitch, yaw) = euler_from_quaternion (orientation_list)
    print yaw

rospy.init_node('my_quaternion_to_euler')

sub = rospy.Subscriber ('/odom', Odometry, get_rotation)

r = rospy.Rate(1)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():    
    quat = quaternion_from_euler (roll, pitch,yaw)
    print quat
    r.sleep()
```

[I have created a video](https://youtu.be/mFpH9KK7GvI) that shows how I applied this code to a Turtlebot 3 robot to get its odometry and then convert it to Euler using that code.

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3